# When should I use OMT instead of UML- class diagram in practice?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Although I found an article about [`OMT`vs. `UML`](http://www.differencebetween.info/difference-between-uml-and-omt) I can't figure out the consequences of using `OMT` instead of `UML- class diagram`. What are the benefits of `OMT` compared to `UML- class diagram`? As far I know I can depict a class diagram in nearly the same way than this is done by using `UML`, or are there any known circumstances where only `OMT` is able to illustrate a specific context? And a bit more interesting question is, what are the criteria used to select between the two modeling tools?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To my knowledge nobody uses OMT anymore. It was superceded by UML; James Rumbaugh was principal in the development of both and a lot of OMT's concepts went straight into UML. So you'd be hard pressed to even find a tool that supports OMT today.

As to the selection criteria, there are two main ones when you choose any form of documentation: is it suitable for what you want to express, and will the audience understand it?

With UML, which is standardized by OMG and for which there are several tools available, the answer might (!) be Yes. With OMT, which is obsolete, it's most likely No.

Comment: Good answer. The goal of UML was to combine the strengths of OMT with other techniques to produce an even better unified approach. I don't think there has been any new work on OMT since the release of UML 1 in 1997. James Rumbaugh himself is now retired.